# Mustache get "this" from a loop

Tags: javascript, mustache

**data**

```
{
  "data": {
    "cats": [
      {
        "name": "Kidlat",
        "age": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Lanaya",
        "age": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Akasha",
        "age": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have an `<select>` looped using mustache like:

```
{{#data.cats}}
<select id="select">
  <option value="{{this}}">{{name}} - {{age}}</option>
</select>
{{/data.cats}}
```

The loop is working fine, however I can't seem to get the object value of the item.

```
$('#clinicSelectMap').on("change", function(e) {
  console.log(this.value); // has value
  console.log(this.value.name); // undefined
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how `this` worked in the callback. `this` referred to the `select` element itself, and calling `console.log(this.value)` had just printed the value which was selected in the dropdown. Note that it is not the same object which you have in your collection.

In fact, you cannot pass the entire object in the HTML template using `this`. Instead, you need to assign the `name` (I'm assuming it is unique) to the `value` attribute and fetch the object using it in the callback.

```
{{#data.cats}}
<select id="select">
  <option value="{{name}}">{{name}} - {{age}}</option>
</select>
{{/data.cats}}

$('#clinicSelectMap').on("change", function(e) {
  var name = this.value;
  var cat = collection.data.cats.find(item => item.name === name);
  console.log(cat);
});
```

Comment: Where did `collection` came from? I got a feeling that this is the global object for the data passed by mustache to html.

Comment: Since you haven't defined a name for the object, I named it `collection` to demonstrate.

Comment: Does mustache put the object in the window object? If so how do I get it?

Comment: @CENT1PEDE -- I'm afraid, I'm not much familiar with mustache, but the point is in HTML, writing `{{this}}` won't yield the object in the callback of dropdown.

Comment: Im getting `data-value="[object Object]"` when I expand the select.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @CENT1PEDE -- Yes, because the string representation of the cat object will be `[object Object]`. That's why use a stringifiable type when binding your own values in HTML. In my answer, I've bound the name of cat as the `value`.